# Wordpress 3.2 Entire page shifted to left in IE7

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on a wordpress 3.2 site and it works fine except all of the content of the #page div is shifted to the left in IE7.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Steph

Comment: Any chance you could drop a link to the actual site?

Failing that, a pastebin of the resulting html code and its css would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

An actual site, code in jsfiddle, access to css.... all that would help on helping you.

My guess: a certain CSS style is not taken properly by the infamous IE7 so the alignment goes wrong.